# Google Cloud Networking - VPC across all projects

Tags: google-cloud-vpn

I'm completely new to Google Cloud.

I want to emulate the traditional networking of VLANs where each VLAN is broken down by function. VLANs would be used by my servers.

Suppose I have 3 VLANs:
1. Presentation layer where I put web servers
2. Data Layer which is where I put my database servers
3. App Layer where I put my application servers

In google cloud:
1. Would each of these VLANs be a shared VPC?
2. As far as I have read VPCs come into being in a project. Does this mean I will need to create a dummy project called say "VPC" which creates these shared VPCs for my other projects to use?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly.
Instead of having several projects (unless you want to)

you can just create a new VPC (for example called MyCompany) and create subnetworks inside it, with your prefer ranges.

For example, creation a subnetworks called WebServers,DataBase and AppServers, each one with a particular range, (for example /24) inside the primary range of the newly VPC create.

You can check more information about how to use the VPC [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc)

Comment: Thanks. So it is possible to add VPCs and subnets without attaching them to a project?

Comment: You will always have at least one project (the one where you are deploying the instances, vpc, firewall rules, etc). But yes, in the main project you are working in, you can have multiple VPC, with multiples subnetworks.